# Insertar datos en tablas relacionadas-. error al insertar

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy insertando datos desde un formulario, a dos tablas relacionadas.

Al momento de enviar los datos solo guarda en una tabla y en la otra no guarda nada. 
me manda el siguiente error

> Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`inversiones`.`proyectos`, CONSTRAINT `proyectos_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id_contacto`) REFERENCES `contacto` (`id_contacto`) ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

Este es mi código php:

```html
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'inversiones';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ('problemas con el servidor');
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db) or die ('problemas con la base de datos');

//recuperamos los valores del formulario
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$web = $_POST['web'];
$proyecto = $_POST['proyecto'];
//$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
$municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
$origen = $_POST['origen'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$inversion = $_POST['inversion'];
$empleos = $_POST['empleos'];
$dependencia = $_POST['dependencia'];
$giro = $_POST['giro'];
$fase = $_POST['fase'];
$estatus = $_POST['estatus'];
$semaforo = $_POST['semaforo'];



$query1  = "INSERT INTO contacto 
            (nombre, telefono, email, direccion, web) VALUES 
            ('$nombre','$telefono','$email','$direccion','$web')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query1);
// Si dio error
if ($resultado === false) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
  die();
}
$var=mysql_insert_id();

//
$query2  = "INSERT INTO proyectos 
           (proyecto,ubicacion, municipio, origen, sector, inversion, empleos, dependencia, giro, fase, id_contacto) VALUES 
           ('$proyecto', '$ubicacion','$municipio','$origen','$sector','$inversion','$empleos','$dependencia','$giro','$fase', '$var')"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
// Si dio error
if ($resultado === false) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
  die();
}

header("Location: form_validation.php");  


 
?>
```

y mi base de datos es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi esta en la relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es la tabla en la que no te guarda?

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner '$var' entre comillas?

Comment: la que dice empresas

Comment: Si ya has obtenido la solución a tu pregunta y ninguna es la correcta, deberías agregar tu respuesta con la solución. Si alguna de las respuesta recibidas es la correcta o te ha sido de ayuda, lo que te corresponde es indicarlo dando clic en las flechas hacia arriba y/o indicando cual es la correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle está en que no puedes primero añadir/actualizar un registro en una tabla que contiene una relación y un campo con una clave foránea.

Lo ideal es que tu primero debes añadir un registro a la tabla que contiene la clave primaria y relacionarla a otra tabla por medio de un campo (que contenga la clave foránea) y sea idéntico TANTO en el tipo de dato como la longitud del dato.

Si tienes alguna duda aún, puedes leer este enlace de MySQL, [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Lo cual ahí dice algo sumamente importante:

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table. The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.
>   They must not be TEMPORARY tables.

Comment: Gracias por el dato saludos!!

Comment: ahí * 

no quita lo correcto de la respuesta, es sólo una observación. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @J.Correa No sabía que utilizarás Stack jaja!

Answer (score 0):

Considera que:

> **[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**: Retorna **FALSE** en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, *mysqli_query()* retornará un objeto [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php). Para otras consultas exitosas de *mysqli_query()* retornará **TRUE**.

//

Con esta info, para saber si dio error y porque, podrias modificar tu script de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'inversiones';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ('problemas con el servidor');
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db) or die ('problemas con la base de datos');

//recuperamos los valores del formulario
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$web = $_POST['web'];
$proyecto = $_POST['proyecto'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
$municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
$origen = $_POST['origen'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$inversion = $_POST['inversion'];
$empleos = $_POST['empleos'];
$dependencia = $_POST['dependencia'];
$giro = $_POST['giro'];
$fase = $_POST['fase'];
$estatus = $_POST['estatus'];
$semaforo = $_POST['semaforo'];

//
$query1  = "INSERT INTO contacto 
            (nombre, telefono, email, direccion, web) VALUES 
            ('$nombre','$telefono','$email','$direccion','$web')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query1);
// Si dio error
if ($resultado === false) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
  die();
}
$var=mysql_insert_id();

//
$query2  = "INSERT INTO empresas 
           (proyecto, empresa, ubicacion, municipio, origen, sector, inversion, empleos, dependencia, giro, fase, id_contacto) VALUES 
           ('$proyecto','$empresa','$ubicacion','$municipio','$origen','$sector','$inversion','$empleos','$dependencia','$giro','$fase', $var)"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
// Si dio error
if ($resultado === false) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
  die();
}

header("Location: form_validation.php");  
?>
```

Comment: Primero gracias por responder a mi pregunta, ya eh intentado de esa manera, me guarda solo contacto y empresas me deja vacio.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta con una pequeña modificación debido a que tenia [un error](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/35216/revisions)

Comment: Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inversiones`.`proyectos`, CONSTRAINT `proyectos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_contacto`) REFERENCES `contacto` (`id_contacto`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)  me lanza este error al parecer dice que algo esta restringiendo hacer un cambio en la tabla.

Comment: Para solucionarlo, necesitaría ver la definición de la tabla `proyectos`. Edita tu pregunta, agrega este error y la exportación de la estructura de las tablas `proyectos`, `contacto` y `empresas`.

Comment: perfecto, gracias en un momento la edito